# MKMapView route update issue

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, mkoverlay

I would like to create a route in mkmapview whenever user moves to some new coordinates, Eg i i am in position A, now i am moving towards position B then the route should also be update.

Thanks

---

I think i didnt provide sufficient information for my issue, Here it is now, I have started  doing cycling from point a and now i am going to point b then c, d etc, But i didnt reached to point b yet, i am in middle of the way, i like to achieve that my route also updates as i move to point b or c, Do i get the updated lat long value from didupdatetolocation delegate method, store them in an array and then draw, Because if i do so, then i am drawing the path everytime from the array? or is there any other approach which only refresh the updated route with the previous path?

Answer (score 0):

By using this you can update the route..

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    // update the route.
}
```

Comment: This will give me the lat and long value whenever i change the location am i right? but then is ia good way to redraw the path with all the array points(Lat and long) again? or is there any way to updated the route only with the new values?

Answer (score 0):

following code is use for the draw path on map.

```
-(void) showRouteFrom: (Place*) f to:(Place*) t {

    if(routes) {
        [mapView removeAnnotations:[mapView annotations]];
        [routes release];
    }

    PlaceMark* from = [[[PlaceMark alloc] initWithPlace:f] autorelease];
    PlaceMark* to = [[[PlaceMark alloc] initWithPlace:t] autorelease];

    [mapView addAnnotation:from];
    [mapView addAnnotation:to];

    routes = [[self calculateRoutesFrom:from.coordinate to:to.coordinate] retain];

    [self updateRouteView];
    [self centerMap];
}
```

[For more detail and sample code grab from here.](http://sugartin.info/2011/10/12/drawing-pathsroutes-on-map-part-2/)

hope this help lot..